# What does (or did) the name "feh" represent?

Tags: history, utilities, conventions

To me, the name of the [feh image viewer](https://linux.die.net/man/1/feh) is not memorable enough for me to recall it when I need it.  I feel that if I had some context, I'd be able to remember it better.

**What, if anything, does the name "feh" stand for?**

Comment: maybe it rhymes with `meh` ... lol

Comment: `not memorable enough for me to recall it` ... create an alias that you will remember

Comment: you'll have to ask Tom Gilbert; hope he's got time, these days he's head of anything web at Deutsche Bank, IIRC.

Comment: The earliest reference I can find is the [Initial announcement](https://groups.google.com/g/fm.announce/c/3e9DUfTpN1w/m/KqrEuIbIz5sJ) from Freshmeat which does not have an explanation of the name. Unfortunately [Freshmeat was hostile to archiving](https://web.archive.org/web/20041115202642/http://apps.freshmeat.net/homepage/951850192/) so I don't know if there was more information there. If you don't need feh's fancier features, `qiv` (“Quick Image Viewer”) may be more memorable.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' So a memory assist emerges: odd-numbered letters of `fresh`.